# Trying to get aria-expanded value in javascript but getting "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the class of a `<span>` tag depending on whether `aria-expanded` is `true` or `false` but it seems to return "undefined" instead so it's not working.

This is my javascript:

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#tester').attr('aria-expanded') === 'true') {
       $("#testerTwo").toggleClass("glyphicon-eye-close glyphicon-eye-open");
    }
});
```

And my html looks like this (using bootstrap):

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <a id="tester" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsible" aria-expanded="false">
        <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Extra <span id="testerTwo" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span></h3>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapsible">
        <div class="card card-block">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is working. what is your problem?

Comment: @Dinesh It's not working for me. When I try `alert($(this).find('a[aria-expanded]').attr('aria-expanded'));` it says "undefined", I think this is why it's not working. Somehow it can't read whether the state is `true` or `false`

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nfmwaeyt/ its working

Comment: @Dinesh Huh, you're right. I have no idea why it's working there but not in my project then. Very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it to click function, you can use selector you want instead of h3. Hope it helps:

```js
$(function () {
 $("h3").click(function () { 
    $("#testerTwo").toggleClass("glyphicon-eye-close glyphicon-eye-open");
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <a id="tester" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsible" aria-expanded="false">
        <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Extra <span id="testerTwo" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span></h3>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapsible">
        <div class="card card-block">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice workaround. (Although I'm still a bit confused as to why my way isn't working.)

Comment: Because you are cliking an element, in your code, you are checking if aria is false or true, but when? You need to check on each click you doing, in this case, toggleclass is enought, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks! I'm still very much a novice so I still need to look into it much more